# How do I use the python eval() function for a tkinter text window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this code, which in essence creates a calculator. The calculator is based upon the eval() function, to evaluate the input in the text field.

```
 from tkinter import *

 tkinter = Tk()

 text = Text(tkinter, font = ('Helvetica', 50), height = 2, width = 20)
 text.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 4)
 def createbutton(number, name, commandname, gridx, gridy):
     def commandname():
         text.insert(END, number)
     name = Button(tkinter, command = commandname, text = number, width = 
 33, height = 4)
     name.grid(row = gridx, column = gridy)
 createbutton('0', 'button0', 'command0', 1, 1)
 createbutton('1', 'button1', 'command1', 1, 2)
 createbutton('2', 'button2', 'command2', 1, 3)

 createbutton('3', 'button3', 'command3', 2, 1)
 createbutton('4', 'button4', 'command4', 2, 2)
 createbutton('5', 'button5', 'command5', 2, 3)

 createbutton('6', 'button6', 'command6', 3, 1)
 createbutton('7', 'button7', 'command7', 3, 2)
 createbutton('8', 'button8', 'command8', 3, 3)

 createbutton('9', 'button9', 'command9', 4, 2)

 createbutton('+', 'additionbutton', 'additioncommand', 4, 1)
 createbutton('-', 'subtractionbutton', 'subtractioncommand', 4, 3)
 createbutton('*', 'multiplicationbutton', 'multiplicationcommand', 5, 1)
 createbutton('÷', 'divisionbutton', 'divisioncommand', 5, 3)

 def equals():
     global evaluate
     evaluate = eval(text)
     text.delete(1.0, END)
     text.insert(END, str(evaluate))

 equalbutton = Button(tkinter, command = equals, text = '=', width = 33, 
 height = 4)
 equalbutton.grid(row = 5, column = 2)
```

The exec() function provides the exact same error,

TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the exception suggest,

```
TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object
```

You should pass **string, bytes or code object** as `eval` parameter. But currently you are passing `Text` widget object.

So in order to work as you expected, get the value from the `Text` widget using `get`.

```
evaluate = eval(text.get("1.0", tk.END))
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because in `eval()` you are passing the instance of `Tkinter.Text` class. I think you want to pass the content of the textbox you get the content like this `text.get(1.0, "end-1c")` that will return you content in string so you should do      `evaluate = eval(text.get(1.0, "end-1c"))`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you pass the text widget itself and not its value to eval. You should use the `.get()` method to take the value from your text widget and only then use `.eval()` on that.

Answer (score 0):

`text` is a `Text` object, not a string, so you can't directly pass that to `eval`.

You need to get the text shown in the `Text` object by using `get`, then pass it to `eval`

```
evaluate = eval(text.get(1.0, END))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `text` in your eval function is your Text Widget, what you want is actually the input inside this widget. Instead of `text` you can try with `text.get("1.0","end-1c")`.

The first part, `1.0` means that the input should be read from line one, character zero. The `end-1c` means to read until the end of the text box is reached, without the last character which is a breaking line character.